# How to remove overlay effect from html canvas image when event occur

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I want to change the t-shirt color with input type color event listener. image is good in canvas. but, whenever the user changes color and an event fires, an overlay effect of that color comes on the image. I wanted to remove that overlay effect.
I wanted the image to look like exactly like as it looks like at starting point with the blue color with no overlay.

```html
<input id="selectedColor" type="color" value="#0000ff">
        <canvas id="myDrawing" width="530" height="600">
```

```
var x; //drawing context
var width; // canvas width
var height; // canvas height
var fg; //image
var buffer; //inner canvas
var color = '#0000ff'; //default color
function shirtColor(){
  return color;
}
function updateShirtColor(){
  //update value of color
  var currentColor = document.getElementById('selectedColor').value;
  color = currentColor;
}
window.onload = function() {
  var myColor = document.getElementById('selectedColor');
  myColor.addEventListener('change',draw);

    var drawingCanvas = document.getElementById('myDrawing');
    // Check the element is in the DOM and the browser supports canvas
    if(drawingCanvas && drawingCanvas.getContext) {
        // Initaliase a 2-dimensional drawing context
        width = drawingCanvas.width;
        height = drawingCanvas.height;
        x = drawingCanvas.getContext('2d');


        // grey box grid for transparency testing
        x.fillStyle = shirtColor();
        x.fillRect(0,0,width,height);
        fg = new Image();
        fg.src = 'https://d1b2zzpxewkr9z.cloudfront.net/images/products/apparel/product_type_1_front.png';

        // create offscreen buffer,
        buffer = document.createElement('canvas');
        buffer.width = fg.width;
        buffer.height = fg.height;
        bx = buffer.getContext('2d');

        // fill offscreen buffer with the tint color
        bx.fillStyle = '#FF';
        bx.fillRect(0,0,buffer.width,buffer.height);

        // destination atop makes a result with an alpha channel identical to fg, but with all pixels retaining their original color *as far as I can tell*
        bx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-atop";
        bx.drawImage(fg,0,0);


        // to tint the image, draw it first
        x.drawImage(fg,0,0);

        //then set the global alpha to the amound that you want to tint it, and draw the buffer directly on top of it.
        x.globalAlpha = 0.5;
        x=x.drawImage(buffer,0,0);
    }
}
function draw(){
  updateShirtColor();
  var drawingCanvas = document.getElementById('myDrawing');
  // Check the element is in the DOM and the browser supports canvas
  if(drawingCanvas && drawingCanvas.getContext) {
      // Initaliase a 2-dimensional drawing context
      width = drawingCanvas.width;
      height = drawingCanvas.height;
      x = drawingCanvas.getContext('2d');
      x.clearRect(0, 0,width,height);
      // grey box grid for transparency testing
      x.fillStyle = shirtColor();
      x.fillRect(0,0,width,height);

      fg = new Image();
      fg.src = 'https://d1b2zzpxewkr9z.cloudfront.net/images/products/apparel/product_type_1_front.png';

      // create offscreen buffer,
      buffer.width = fg.width;
      buffer.height = fg.height;
      bx = buffer.getContext('2d');

      // fill offscreen buffer with the tint color
      bx.clearRect(0, 0, buffer.width, buffer.height);
      bx.fillStyle = '#FF';
      bx.fillRect(0,0,buffer.width,buffer.height);

      // destination atop makes a result with an alpha channel identical to fg, but with all pixels retaining their original color *as far as I can tell*
      bx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-atop";
      bx.drawImage(fg,0,0);


      // to tint the image, draw it first
      x.drawImage(fg,0,0);

      //then set the global alpha to the amound that you want to tint it, and draw the buffer directly on top of it.
      x.globalAlpha = 0.5;
      x=x.drawImage(buffer,0,0);
  }
}
```

I expect to have clear image without overlay effect after color change event occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not very sure this is what you were asking. You have an error in your code. You try to draw the image before it's loaded. I've wrapped that part of code in `fg.onload = function() {....}`

A second error you have: in the function `draw` you create a new image every time you call the function. You don't need to. You already have the `fg` variable. Just use it.

```js
var x; //drawing context
var width; // canvas width
var height; // canvas height
var fg; //image
var buffer; //inner canvas
var color = "#0000ff"; //default color
function shirtColor() {
  return color;
}
function updateShirtColor() {
  //update value of color
  var currentColor = document.getElementById("selectedColor").value;
  color = currentColor;
}
window.onload = function() {
  var myColor = document.getElementById("selectedColor");
  myColor.addEventListener("change", draw);

  var drawingCanvas = document.getElementById("myDrawing");
  // Check the element is in the DOM and the browser supports canvas
  if (drawingCanvas && drawingCanvas.getContext) {
    // Initaliase a 2-dimensional drawing context
    width = drawingCanvas.width;
    height = drawingCanvas.height;
    x = drawingCanvas.getContext("2d");

    // grey box grid for transparency testing
    x.fillStyle = shirtColor();
    x.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
    fg = new Image();
    fg.src =
      "https://d1b2zzpxewkr9z.cloudfront.net/images/products/apparel/product_type_1_front.png";
    fg.onload = function() {
      // create offscreen buffer,
      buffer = document.createElement("canvas");
      buffer.width = fg.width;
      buffer.height = fg.height;
      bx = buffer.getContext("2d");

      // fill offscreen buffer with the tint color
      bx.fillStyle = "#FF";
      bx.fillRect(0, 0, buffer.width, buffer.height);

      // destination atop makes a result with an alpha channel identical to fg, but with all pixels retaining their original color *as far as I can tell*
      bx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-atop";
      bx.drawImage(fg, 0, 0);

      // to tint the image, draw it first
      x.drawImage(fg, 0, 0);

      //then set the global alpha to the amound that you want to tint it, and draw the buffer directly on top of it.
      //x.globalAlpha = 0.5;
      //x=x.drawImage(buffer,0,0);
    };
  }
};
function draw() {
  updateShirtColor();
  var drawingCanvas = document.getElementById("myDrawing");
  // Check the element is in the DOM and the browser supports canvas
  if (drawingCanvas && drawingCanvas.getContext) {
    // Initaliase a 2-dimensional drawing context
    width = drawingCanvas.width;
    height = drawingCanvas.height;
    x = drawingCanvas.getContext("2d");
    x.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
    // grey box grid for transparency testing
    x.fillStyle = shirtColor();
    x.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);

      // create offscreen buffer,
      buffer.width = fg.width;
      buffer.height = fg.height;
      bx = buffer.getContext("2d");

      // fill offscreen buffer with the tint color
      bx.clearRect(0, 0, buffer.width, buffer.height);
      bx.fillStyle = "#FF";
      bx.fillRect(0, 0, buffer.width, buffer.height);

      // destination atop makes a result with an alpha channel identical to fg, but with all pixels retaining their original color *as far as I can tell*
      bx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-atop";
      bx.drawImage(fg, 0, 0);

      // to tint the image, draw it first
      x.drawImage(fg, 0, 0);

      //then set the global alpha to the amound that you want to tint it, and draw the buffer directly on top of it.
      //x.globalAlpha = 0.5;
      //x=x.drawImage(buffer,0,0);
    
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="selectedColor" type="color" value="#0000ff">
        <canvas id="myDrawing" width="530" height="600">
```